# Custom scoring function GridsearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring, gridsearchcv

I would like to implement a custom scoring function for a GridsearchCV. I tried to look at this example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110599/how-to-get-both-mse-and-r2-from-a-sklearn-gridsearchcv, but my code ends up in a kind of infinite loop, it keeps running without giving any results... Here is the code I am using:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer

def my_custom_loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    ps = precision_score(y_true, y_pred)    
    perc_bet =  np.count_nonzero(y_pred)/len(y_pred)

    result = (ps + perc_bet) / (1/ps)

    return result

scorer = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)

model = SGDClassifier(random_state=0)
grid_values = {
    'tol': [0.0001, 0.005]
}

grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid = grid_values, scoring=scorer, n_jobs=-1, return_train_score=False)
grid.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

print('Grid best parameter: ', grid.best_params_)
print('Grid best score: ', grid.best_score_)
```

I am running this code in a Jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the output of your function? If you have python 2 those divisions may always return zero e.g. 1/5 is 0 in python2.

Comment: Try with `n_jobs=1` first.